# Unitialized Class Calling Function, No exception. What is going on here?

Tags: c++

Is this normal behavior; this never happened to me before. I assume it would cause an exception but why doesn't it here? Take a look.

```
CWindowsApplication::MsgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static CWindowApplication* pApp = NULL;

    if (message == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
    //// retrieve Window instance from window creation data and associate
    //pApp = reinterpret_cast(((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->lpCreateParams); 
    //::SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast(pApp));

    //pApp = reinterpret_cast(::GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_USERDATA));
    }

    pApp->WndProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam); // pApp = NULL, but it still works? I expected a exception of some sort. 
}
```

But, when I change the class to something else I get the exception I was expecting.
What is going on here? Never in my 10+ years as an enthusiastic programmer have I ever came across something like this.

Comment: WndProc probably doesn't actually touch any local members, so it never dereferences this, so no exception.  (IE, function could be or is `static`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as `WndProc` is not virtual, the pointer technically doesn't need to be dereferenced at all in order to make the call.  That's not to say it won't crash and burn when you try to use `this` (including calling any virtual function with an implicit `this`) inside `WndProc`, but non-virtual calls go by the type of the pointer, and don't need to touch the vtable (or any other instance member).

Comment: Thank you! Changed it to a pure virtual function and I got the exception i was expecting. I assume this will be a safer way.

Answer (score 2):

All you're doing is invoking undefined behaviour. That means that it can appear to work, it can crash, or whatever the compiler feels like making it do.